# Corda: Does transaction builder automatically add reference states in Corda 4.0?

Tags: corda

Question on Reference states in C4: If a state has two fields of type LinearPointer then does corda automatically resolves those 2 pointers and adds them to the tx.reference states *even if not added in the flow code*?  If yes, any reason why corda is doing that? I am referring to the below function:
https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/6769b00ed5249e2eb798428a35e54ab740cf3bee/core/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/core/transactions/TransactionBuilder.kt#L540

it is called every time we call addInput, addOutput, etc..

For example:

```
data class IOUState(val value: Int,
                    val lenderParty: Party,
                    val borrowerParty: Party,
                    val lender: LinearPointer<IDState>,
                    val borrower: LinearPointer<IDState>,
                    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()):
```

I only wish to add lender to the reference states, but i noticed that corda internally adds borrower to tx. referencestates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! It does get added automatically.

If you do not want the states auto added as ref states then just add the linear ID in the state and not a linear pointer. so make lender a linear pointer and borrower a linearId. That should solve the problem!

The reason why ref states are automatically added is to give you the extra assurance that they are 1) current and 2) have verified chains of provenance. 
Also, this way, they can be easily resolved by counter-parties.